# I can't get logging.config to load my custom class

Tags: python, python-logging

I have a custom formatter defined in my log_conf.py.

```
# log_conf.py
class Custom(jsonlogger.JsonFormatter):
    def add_fields(self, log_record, record, message_dict):
        super().add_fields(log_record, record, message_dict)
        log_record["new_field"] = log_record["levelname"]

logging.config.fileConfig(file_path)

def get_logger(name):
    return logging.getLogger(name)
```

In my logger.ini file I reference it like this:

```
....
[formatter_json]
class = log_conf.Custom
```

If I throw my log_conf.py and logger.ini in the same module that is using it this works:

```
from my_project.my_module import log_conf
log = log_conf.get_logger(__name__)
```

But I want to put it in a different folder like this:

```
my_project
    main.py
    my_module/
        stuff.py
    myconf/
        logger.ini
        log_conf.py
```

If I use this structure and do `from my_project.myconf import log_conf` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'log_conf'`.

If I change the ini file to `class = myconf.log_conf.Custom` it still can't find it.

If I change it to `class = my_project.myconf.log_conf.Custom` I get `AttributeError: cannot access submodule 'log_config' of module 'my_project.myconf' (most likely due to a circular import)`.

Why does it work when they are in the module's dir and throw circular import when using the full namespace of the Custom class for `class=`?

Comment: `import my_project.myconf.log_conf`?

Comment: I'm confused about what your suggesting, I'm already doing `from my_project.myconf import log_conf` if I do something like `import my_project.myconf.log_conf as conf` I get the same circular import error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized the problem was having my custom class defined in the same file that was loading the config duh.

If the file that is calling `logging.config.fileConfig("logging_ini_file")` includes the class the ini file is pointing to ie: `class = myproj.mymodule.file_that_loaded_this_ini_with_fileConfig.CustomThing` you get a circular import because fileConfig() is trying to re-import the file that called it.